# Post request from ReactJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I want to receive the post request from front end using ReactJs. The api is working and i get a get request, also my React Component is working.
This is my post request from the React component:

```
function submitBtn() {
    
return (
 fetch("api", {
  method: "POST",
  headers : { 
  'Content-Type':'application/json',
  'Accept':'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify('my data')
  }).then(res => {
  console.log("Request complete! response:", res);
   })
    )
     }
  return (
       <div>
            <input ref={nameRef} type='text' placeholder='name' name='firstName' />
            <input ref={lastnameRef} type='text' placeholder='last name' name='lastName' />
         <button onClick={submitBtn} type='submit'>Fetch</button>
      </div>
    )
    ...
```

Bellow is my NodeJs code:

```
    app.post('/api', function (req, res) {
       console.log("Got a POST request");
       res.json({ username: req.body.firstName, lastname: req.body.lastName  });
       res.sendStatus(200);
    })
```

Also, i used bodyParser. 
The problem is that i can't receive data from my post request? What could be the issue? 
Also i get the issue: `Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0`. What this could be in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is not correct. While sending fetch request body must be stringified JSON.

```js
function submitBtn() {
    
return (
 fetch("api", {
  method: "POST",
  headers : { 
  'Content-Type':'application/json',
  'Accept':'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({firstName: "toto", lastName: "momo"})
  }).then(res => {
  console.log("Request complete! response:", res);
   })
    )
     }
  return (
       <div>
            <input ref={nameRef} type='text' placeholder='name' name='firstName' />
            <input ref={lastnameRef} type='text' placeholder='last name' name='lastName' />
         <button onClick={submitBtn} type='submit'>Fetch</button>
      </div>
    )
    ...
```

Here's an example: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/fetch-api/fetch-post.html

Comment: i got the next error: `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: app.post('/api', function (req, res) { console.log("Got a POST request");  res.send({ username: req.body.firstName, lastname: req.body.lastName }); })


Youre sending response twice. Try above code

Comment: Cool!! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

keep the following things in mind:

1. body data should be stringified for `"Content-Type": "application/json"` when 
   using **fetch**:

   `body: JSON.stringify(object)`
2. `res.json({ username: req.body.firstName, lastname: req.body.lastName  });` will automatically set status as 200 and will end `req-res` cycle. So calling `res.sendSatatus()` will throw error because `req-res` cycle has already ended.
3. if you want to set status manually with data use

   `res.status('statusCode').json(object)`